# Firefox OS WebFM API - LF or MF

Tags: javascript, firefox-os, fm-radio, webfm-api

The [**WebFM API**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FMRadio) provides access to the device FM radio.

You can set the frequency with `FMRadio.setFrequency()`.

Does the WebFM API for Firefox OS support `LF` and `MF` too, or does it only work with `VHF`?

```
 - LF   Low Frequency        30–300 kHz
 - MF   Medium Frequency     0,3–3  MHz
 - VHF  Very High Frequency  30–300 MHz
```

Unfortunately, the specification at MDN is not clear enough.

Comment: I think this is most likely device-dependent, May be related: [`FMRadio.frequencyLowerBound`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FMRadio.frequencyLowerBound)

Comment: I don't think it's device dependent. The WebFM API is a part of firefox-os. But `FMRadio.frequencyLowerBound` can't switch to `kHz` (Low Frequency), because the range starts at 1 `MhZ`.

Comment: I meant device dependent as in the hardware would need to support it, e.g. most FM radios (VHF) do not support tuning to AM frequencies (usually in MF), and it's not just because you can't twist the dial far enough. Also, I don't see where on _MDN_ it says `FMRadio.frequencyLowerBound` must be an integer (it's a _double_) or will always be at least `1`

Answer (score 2):

It's depend on a Gecko pref, which is set by the hardware vendor, so, yes, it's device dependent.

http://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/dom/fmradio/FMRadioService.cpp#64-78

Comment: ... and none of the value of the pref goes to `LF` or `VHF`.

Answer (score 2):

All the attributes related to frequency (i.e. frequency, channelWidth, frequencyLowerBound, frequencyUpperBound) are in MHz, so technically MF should be supported, but LF won't.

The WebFM API is not a standard API yet (it's moz prefixed: navigator.mozFMRadio), it only works on Firefox OS and device dependent as @timdream said.

BTW, you could find the WebFM API discussion here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/mozilla.dev.webapi/PraULCQntqA

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=779500